# Don't want decimal value in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, decimal

I dont want to allow the decimal values in text box.. I have written the code but it works only if you remove the whole value and then reinsert it.. 
My issue is when I try to edit the existing value it take the decimal numbers.. 
[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUj8M/4/). This is code for reference:

**HTML**

```
<input id="Amt"  type="text" value="$78.00">
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Amt").keydown(function (e) {
        if ((!e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey) && ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) ||
                (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105))) {
        }
        else if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 39 &&
                     e.keyCode != 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

   $("#Amt").keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
       var newValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
        if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
            $(this).val(newValue);
            $(this).caret(newValue.length - 3, newValue.length - 3);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue is that you are validating/filtering on keyup. Could you do it on blur instead?

Comment: hmm sorry not getting you...@geedubb...are you suggesting me to change the event??

Comment: are you trying to prevent the user from entering a `.` character into the text box?  
  
or are you trying to prevent a value like `3.14` from being saved to javascript after the user entered a value?  
  
or would you want to round the user's answer up or down to an integer value with two decimal places?  
  
It looks like the user can enter `78`, and you will produce `78.00` for them? is this what you want?  did you want the user to only enter whole dollars? and you will append the `.00` to any value?

Comment: yes i want user just to add the the whole amount ..but this value is comming out of a different form and is coming in this format $78.00..and before submitting the cart the user can edit this amount in cart but while editing it takes the decimal value..which i dont want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string methods to chop out the decimal and re-append '.00' if you want to keep this format.

```
  $("#Amt").blur(function (e) {
    var value = this.value.replace(/\$/g,"");
    var dotPos = value.indexOf(".");
    var dollars = dotPos>-1?value.substring(0,dotPos):value;
    $(this).val(dollars+".00");
  });

  $("#Amt").blur();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUj8M/14/

Comment: can you please answer one more thing ...is it posible to truncate $ symbol on the document load????

Comment: You want to remove the $ from the input field? Can you be sure that it will be populated at document ready?

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it in a completely different way, just prevent the decimal from getting there in the first place. http://jsfiddle.net/ZUj8M/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var timer;
  $("#Amt").on("keydown paste input",function (e) {
    var el = this,
      origval = this.value;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      if (origval != el.value && /\./.test(el.value)) {
        el.value = origval;
        alert("Decimals are not allowed in this field.");
      }
    }, 0);
  });
  if (/\./.test($("#Amt").val())) {
    $("#Amt").val($("#Amt").val().replace(/\./g,""));
  }

});
```

alternatively you could instead of undoing the change, simply remove the decimal.

```
// el.value = origval;
// alert("Decimals are not allowed in this field.");
el.value = el.value.replace(/\./g,"");
```

Comment: i dont have the control of this value its coming in as $78.00 onto the cart..i just want to restrict the decimal entry once its in cart...

Comment: @Scorpio I fixed that by adding the if statement after binding. The if statement removes the existing decimal, then the keydown prevents it from coming back.

Answer (score 0):

why not parsing the given value to Integer?

```
var newValue = parseInt(floatValue, 10);
```

then allow the users to insert a dot "." and on .blur()-event you can parse the float to int...

```
$("#Amt").blur(function() {
    $this.val(parseInt(jQuery(this).val(), 10));
});
```